# Why visual studio runs my solution only in debug mode?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, release

I've been coding for some months and testing everything in debug mode, and all was working fine but now that I have to archive the release package to test on android devices, Visual Studio fails with the below output. The problem seems to be Stormlion.ImageCropper.ImageCropper but why this works as expected in debug mode? Is there a way to fix that or I have to remove this package?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(5,5): Error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Stormlion.ImageCropper.ImageCropper/<Show>d__43::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Stormlion.ImageCropper.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia::TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00013] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x0004a] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00040] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000c2] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x00186] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001b] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x00047] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue () [0x0000a] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process () [0x00102] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000d] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000b] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000d] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x001dd] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask () [0x0001b] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <82010c32869043cdad86578a8131c7e9>:0  (XALNK7000) (MasterDetailPageNavigation.Droid)
```

Comment: You might get some ideas from posts like https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9724 Upgrade your VS and/or the NuGet packages.